# Update trigger behavior in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I used an Update statement inside a procedure to update a table which has an update trigger. Does the update statement complete after the trigger completes or what?

Answer (score 2):

the trigger runs as part of the UPDATE statement (after the data in the table has been updated); the proc resumes after this. There are also "instead of" triggers that *replace* the UPDATE statement.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of triggers in SQL Servers.  INSTEAD OF triggers, and AFTER triggers.  By default, a trigger is an AFTER trigger, meaning this is what happens.  Consider TableA, with an UPDATE AFTER TRIGGER which updates TableB.

- Issue statement: UPDATE TableA set XXX = 5;
- TableA gets updated
- The trigger fires, and TableB gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

triggers are attached to the statement(s) that trigger them and are implicitly the part of transaction that fired them.

For ex :

if triggers are fired because of update , then it helps to understand that database would implicitly insert a *begin tran* and *end tran* surrounding that update.